# Laravel - Form Action to Controller Function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a situation where a user can load a page, select a timesheet number, and then have the system delete all records associated with that timesheet number. This function loads the form page:

```
 public function deletetimesheetLoad()
{

    $timesheets = collect(DB::select("SELECT dbo.TIME.Source AS Source
        FROM dbo.TIME
        GROUP BY dbo.TIME.Source
        ORDER BY dbo.TIME.Source ASC"));

    return view('utilities/deletetimesheet',['timesheets' => $timesheets]);
}
```

This is the actual blade template:

```
 <form method="post"
            action="{{url('/time/deletetimesheet/process')}}"
            enctype="multipart/form-data"
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="TIMESHEETNUMBER">Timesheet Number</label>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <select required id="TIMESHEETNUMBER" name="TIMESHEETNUMBER" class="form-control select2_field">
                <option value=""></option>
            @foreach ($timesheets as $row)
                <option value="{{ $row->Source }}">{{ $row->Source }}</option>
            @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
 <div id="saveActions" class="form-group">

            <input type="hidden" name="save_action" value="Submit">

            <div class="btn-group">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <span class="fa fa-save"></span> &nbsp;
                    <span data-value="Submit">Submit</span>
                </button>
        </div>

            <a href="" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-ban"></span> &nbsp;Cancel</a>
        </div>
```

This is the function that the form action is pointing to:

```
 public function deletetimesheetProcess(TimesheetRequest $request)
{

   DB::table('TIME')->where('Source', $request->get('TIMESHEETNUMBER'))->delete();

   \Alert::success(trans('yay'))->flash();

   return view('details/customershow',[]);

}
```

Here are the defined routes for the two functions:

```
 Route::get('/time/deletetimesheet', 'Admin\TimeCrudController@deletetimesheetLoad');
 Route::post('/time/deletetimesheet/process', 'Admin\TimeCrudController@deletetimesheetProcess');
```

Currently the blade template loads correctly, and does not throw an error on submit - just reloads the current page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you close `</form>` tag??

Comment: Yes the form tag is closed

Comment: is it a copy past error or the form opening tag doesn't have a closing `>` ?

Comment: The form is properly closed, i didn't include the whole blade in the post